# How to move the prebuilt storage things in my freighter?

Tags: no-mans-sky

In the large room inside my freighter there are some prebuilt storage things, like the two red cylindric containers in upright position, the green broken computer, a lamp and others.

How can I move them to another place in my freighter?
I know that I can destroy them with <kbd>Z</kbd> and then press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> while pointing to the unwanted item and click the left mouse button.
But how can I rebuild them at a more conventient place?

[image]

And the second question about this items:
**Who or what is filling them during my absence?**

Answer (score 1):

You can't move the barrels, only delete them. However, you **can** build new ones, by unlocking the ["Barrel Fabricator" blueprint](https://nomanssky.gamepedia.com/Blueprint_Analyser#Group_5_blueprints_.28limit_6.29) from the blueprint analyzer (#55 on the linked list.) The behaviour of that blueprint is identical.

As for who's filling them, it seems they automatically fabricate new products based on the name.

Comment: The same holds true for the green container to the right of the barrell containers in your image. You get to build as many as you want once you have the blueprint unlocked and the materials to build them. A good way to collect and farm relics and other misc. items. The game will refill those containers in your freighter every time you warp or summon the freighter to a new location.